# Page loading of NextJS production build is too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to NextJS, and I've deployed to Netlify as a production build. However, when I navigate to a page using next router, it takes about 3-4 seconds to load on a specific page. But strangely, it works fast in the local dev environment.

[image]

```
interface Props {
  id: string;
}

const Profile: NextPage<Props> = ({ id }) => {
  const subMenuData: any = {
    posts: '게시글',
    likes: '좋아요',
    // playings: '연주',
    lessons:  '레슨',
    reviews: '리뷰',
    // requests: '레슨신청'
  }

  const [ subMenu, setSubMenu ] = useState<string>('posts');

  const songData: IData[] = [ ...Array(12) ];
  songData.map((v,k) => {
    songData[k] = { title: '너를 만나', artist: '풀킴', rate:4 };
  })

  return (
    <PageRoot className={styles.root}>
      {/* <PageNav className={styles.nav}>
        프로필
      </PageNav> */}
      <PageContent className={styles.content}>
        <div className={styles.profile}>
          <span onClick={() => moveUrl('/profile/update')}>
            내 프로필 수정 <MdArrowForwardIos />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.info}>
          <div className={styles.img}>
            {/* <Image /> */}
          </div>
          <div className={styles.basic}>
            <div className={styles.top}>
              방구석 뮤지션
            </div>
            <div className={styles.middle}>
              3년 미만 중급자
            </div>
            <div className={styles.bottom}>
              <span>피아노</span>
              <span>기타</span>
              <span>드럼</span>
              <span>바이올린</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.settings}>
            <div className={styles.top}>
              설정
            </div>
            <div className={styles.middle}>
              고객센터 <MdArrowForwardIos />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.bottom}>
              <span>회원탈퇴</span>
              <Button onClick={()=>{}}>
                로그아웃
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <nav className={styles.submenu}>
          <ul>
            {Object.keys(subMenuData).map((v)=>{
              return (
                <li
                  className={v===subMenu ? styles.active:''}
                  onClick={e => clickSubMenu(e,v)}
                  key={v}
                >
                  {subMenuData[v]}
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        
        { subMenu==='posts' &&
          <PostsContainer className={styles.posts} showFilterPost={false} showTitle={false} />
        }

        <div className={styles.content}>
          { subMenu==='likes' &&
            <MyPageLikesContainer />
          }

          {/* { subMenu==='playings' &&
            <SongsContainer className={styles.songs} data={songData} />
          } */}

          { subMenu==='lessons' &&
            <MyPageLessonsContainer songData={songData} />
          }

          {/* { subMenu==='requests' &&
            <MyPageRequestsContainer data={songData} />
          } */}

          { subMenu==='reviews' &&
            <MyPageReviewsContainer />
          }
        </div>
      </PageContent>
    </PageRoot>
  )

  function clickSubMenu(e: React.MouseEvent, key: string) {
    setSubMenu(key);
  }
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const props = {
    id: context.query.id
  }

  return {
    props
  }
};

export default Profile;
```

I set the image to lazy loading, but it didn't help to reduce the loading time.

How can I reduce the loading time?

Comment: It looks like most of the work is getting the user json if I'm reading the image on mobile correctly.

Comment: Yes, I checked that too, but I don't know why it's so slow in the production environment while it is fast in the dev environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your answer in your Network screenshot.

You are fetching a userId.json resource, which takes 2.92s to return. It has nothing to do with your Profile component.

Try displaying a loader or some sort while waiting for the request to complete. In any case don't block the rendering while waiting for this type of user specific resource

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to reduce the fetch time of userId.json resource? It works fast in local dev environment, but slow in production environment.

Comment: where are you fetching the json from? is it deployed on a different server in production? are you doing any database access and data manipulation to generate that file? In that case, your server might not have the same resource as your computer especially if it's on a shared hosting solution where the load on the server can have a big impact on the response time, and if the server is located in another region, you will have more latency. Other criteria can come into play.

Comment: Yes, Production is temporarily deploying to Netlify for testing. I built NextJS locally and ran the server locally and found it to be fast. As you said, it seems that the Netlify server is in a different region. If I'm wrong, please leave a comment.

Comment: This is a terrible answer btw
i'm sure userId.json is like 1KB and it takes forever to load. Theres something wrong with nextjs when it comes to first load

Comment: I'm deploying in the GKE environment, and it's working fine in now.